# how to set a custom qfilesystemmodel in qfiledialog

Tags: qt, qml, qfiledialog, qfilesystemmodel

I'd like to show a virtual file system alongside the normal file system in a qml file dialog. For that virtual file system i will use a customized class derived from qfilesystemmodel.

However how can i tell the qml file dialog to use my custom model?

I have seen in the
qml/QtQuick/Dialogs/DefaultFileDialog.qml source code, that it has a `modelComponent` property but I don't know how to modify that property. Can anybody help? Is this even the right way to achieve it or should it be done in another way?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html) ? it has an example that uses [FolderListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html) as its model.

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.